# How to assign incremental-value to the list in java 8

Tags: java, java-8

You assume that there are a list of an object. The list is sorted by one or more field of that object. So according to sorted list, i want to set a field of that object with incremental-value.
For clarifying, pay attention to the below example:

```
public class ObjectTest {
   int id;
   int userId;
   int code;
}
```

As above ObjectTest, any user has its own code.
There are a list of ObjectTest.

```
List<ObjectTest> objTests;
```

It is sorted:

```
objTests.sort(Comparator.comparing(DataSet::getUserId).thenComparing(DataSet::getCode));
```

So after sorting by userId and code, i want to set value from 1 to where any user has the its own code. The incremental value again is resetted to 1 when userId is changed.

If there are the following collection of ObjectTest.

```
    id     userId    code
--------------------------------
             100     5
             200     6
             100     7
             200     9
             200     10
             100     2
```

After the above scenario that is explained, the following collection will be:

```
id      userId     code
1        100        2
2        100        5
3        100        7
1        200        6
2        200        9
3        200        10
```

Is it possible with lambda expression in java

Answer (score 5):

Something along the lines of this should work:

```
List<ObjectTest> resultSet = 
objTests.stream()
        .sorted(Comparator.comparing(ObjectTest::getUserId).thenComparing(ObjectTest::getCode))
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(ObjectTest::getUserId, LinkedHashMap::new, Collectors.toList()))
        .values()
        .stream()
        .map(e -> {
            IntStream.range(0, e.size())
                    .forEach(i -> e.get(i).setId(i + 1));
            return e;
        })
        .flatMap(Collection::stream)
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Note, I have not compiled this code.

Comment: Compiles fine, altough IntelliJ complains with `.map()` because it could be replaced with `.peek()` as it has only sideeffects and doesn't change anything from the variable `e` ;)

Comment: @Lino I'd avoid using `peek` here as that's not its intended purpose. but one can always create a method to clone the objects in the list `e` and _then_ set the ids and return the new list. btw thanks for clarifying that it compiles ;) .

Comment: You're welcome, and right ;) You might even want to change the `.map()` to a .`forEach()` because of the side-effects and then get rid of the flatmap and collect. Which IMO would be the most clear answer there is

Comment: How to shift to the end in list If there are some null value?

Comment: @rezaramezanimatin use this comparator `Comparator.nullsLast(Comparator.comparingInt(ObjectTest::getUserId))
                                          .thenComparing(Comparator.comparingInt(ObjectTest::getCode))` then change `ObjectTest::getUserId` in the groupingBy to `e -> e != null ? e.getUserId() : Integer.MAX_VALUE` and the `forEach` to `IntStream.range(0, e.size()).filter(i -> e.get(i) != null).forEach(i -> e.get(i).setId(i + 1))` or in JDK-9 `IntStream.range(0, e.size()).takeWhile(i -> e.get(i) != null).forEach(i -> e.get(i).setId(i + 1))`

Comment: I don’t think that using `map` for this purpose is better than using `peek`, both methods are not intended for such things. By the way, you could simplify the first part to `… .sorted(Comparator.comparing(ObjectTest::getCode)) .collect(Collectors.groupingBy( ObjectTest::getUserId, TreeMap::new, Collectors.toList())) …`. In the second part, you can combine the `map` and `flatMap` steps: `.flatMap(e -> IntStream.range(0, e.size()) .mapToObj(i -> { ObjectTest o = e.get(i); o.setId(i + 1); return o; }))`

Answer (score 2):

You can create a map of `userId` to a scoped atomic integer object, then iterate over the sorted list to set the ID.

```
Map<Integer, AtomicInteger> userIds = 
        objTests.stream()
        .map(obj -> Integer.valueOf(obj.getUserId()))
        .distinct()
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(Function.identity(), 
                 (id) -> new AtomicInteger(1)));
```

The above map contains an atomic integer object for each unique `userId`.

```
objTests.stream()
        .forEach(obj -> obj.setId(userIds.get(obj.getUserId())
                                   .getAndIncrement()));
```

This last code just iterates over the sorted list, then assigns an `id` read from the atomic integer associated with the user ID on the instance.

Comment: @YCF_L I probably do (it has to start at 1...). Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

It may be possible but you should most likely not solve it with the *streams API*.

The reason is that the *streams API* ist Javas implementation of *functional programming* and one of the key assumptions in FP is that objects (or better any data) have *no relationship to each other* **and** *no function changes the state of the Input data*.

Therefore your requirement breakes with FPs key assumption.

> What is your idea to get my goal? – reza ramezani matin

Group objects by user ID:

```
Map<Integer,ObjectTest> userIdMap= objTests.stream()
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
                           ot ->ot.userId , ot ->ot
                    ));
```

enumerate with legacy Looping:

```
for(Collection<ObjectTest> ol : userIdMap.values()){
   objectList = new ArrayList(ol);
   Colections.sort(ol, /* comparator here*/);
   for(int id = 0; id < ol.size();)
      objectList.get(id).id=++id;
}
```

Comment: What is your idea to get my goal?

Comment: @rezaramezanimatin You can just loop elements with a plain old for loop and do your business. The stream API and the stream way of handling the data is not always the best solution.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @Varvarigos Emmanouil, Sometimes it's easier to do without Stream API.

```
Collections.sort(list, Comparator.comparing(ObjectTest::getUserId).thenComparing(ObjectTest::getCode));
int userId = list.get(0).userId;
int index = 0;
for (ObjectTest objectTest:list){
     if (userId != objectTest.userId){
          index = 0;
          userId = objectTest.userId;
     }
      objectTest.setId(++index);
}
```